# Git cannot push to remote bare repo

Tags: git, githooks, git-remote, git-bare

**What I would like to do :**
I would like to create a remote that points to a bare git repository on a vps server accessible through ssh. This bare repository will embed a hook to fetch the latest branch version into another directory on the same vps server.

**Where I'm stuck :**

- The bare repository is created on vps server
- The remote is created from local computer
- The server is accessible via SSH
- When performing "git push production master" with *production* being my remote name, git just stops without exiting leaving the following prompt :

[image]

Here is the part of my .git/config file for the remote definition

[image]

Whether the hook is enabled or not, it gives me the same output. Do you have any hint on what is wrong here ? I checked the remote repositories are both

- at the correct path
- with a correct permission set

Thank you for your time.

Comment: please present text not pictures here! Nobody can search or copy photos!

Comment: What kind of information would you want to copy from these captures ?

Comment: Sorry, I did a downvote? BTW: It is quite common to put simple text here. All posts can be searched ( also from internet search engines ). I don't know why it is important for you to keep the pictures. But it is up to you... I dislike photos here! There are rare cases where we need to view a gui or something else. But this is not the case here!

Comment: Alright, I just don't see what part of it could be useful, there are no specific error messages, I just wanted to show the situation on my prompt so ... I doesn't really matter here I agree, but neither putting it as text so... Sorry for triggering you, wasn't my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the remote bare git folder was in www-data ownership, not in the used ssh user ownership. Everything is working fine now.
Regards & Sorry.